# Want Schedule Queueable apex job for every 20min , is it possible?

Tags: scheduled-apex

I have below Queueable class and want it schedule in each 20min, Please help me how we can do ?

```
public class ExploreQueue implements System.Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts{

public void execute(QueueableContext content){
//logic 
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't schedule a job for less than an hour interval. Your two basic options are to either schedule three jobs (e.g. at :00, :20, and :40), or have the job abort itself (System.abortJob) and schedule a new job 20 minutes out. It's strongly recommended that you simply schedule 3 jobs.

Edit: As it was pointed out to me via DM, it is not directly possible to schedule Queueable classes.

Two basic options we have to work around this are to: (a) write a way to schedule the class with Schedulable, or (b) enable the class to be called through a Scheduled Flow.

The first method could be to write a wrapper:

```
public class ScheduleQueueable implements Schedulable {
  public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
    Queueable q = new Queueable();
    System.enqueueJob(q);
  }
}
```

Or dynamically, passing in an existing Queuable:

```
public class ScheduleQueueable implements Schedulable {
  Queueable q;
  // factory methods
  public static ScheduleQueueable enqueueJob(Queueable q) {
    return new SchedulableQueueable(q);
  }
  ScheduleQueueable(Queueable q) {
    this.q = q;
  } 
  public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
    System.enqueueJob(q);
  }
}
```

Or by enabling the class itself as Schedulable:

```
public class MyQueueable implements Schedulable, Queueable {
  public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
    System.enqueueJob(this);
  }
  public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    // Business logic here
  }
}
```

---

We can also implement the InvocableMethod/InvocableVariable annotations and make something we can call through a flow.

```
public class CallQueueable {
    @InvocableMethod(description='Calls a Queueable by name') public static void callQueueable(String[] name) {
        for(String className: name) {
            Queueable q = (Queueable)Type.forName(className).newInstance();
            System.enqueueJob(q);
        }
    }
}
```

This can call any Queueable that takes zero parameters and execute it, and we can call this from a Scheduled Flow.

There's a lot of flexibility here, once you realize that there are many different ways to call Queueable that also allow scheduling.